# Fetching email from android subscription customer on in-app purchase

Tags: android

After a user makes an android in-app subscription purchase, what's the best way to get the buyer's email address?

After a purchase is made, I get from Google Play: order_id, package_name, product_id, purchase_time, purchase_state, purchase_token.

We were using the Notification History API [1] to fetch the buyer's email address from google checkout, which used to be listed on buyer-billing-address. For some reason, though, the billing address on our XML responses no longer include an email node:

```
<notification-history-response xmlns="http://checkout.google.com/schema/2" serial-number="X">
  <notifications>
    <new-order-notification serial-number="X">
      <buyer-billing-address>
        <structured-name>
          <first-name>John</first-name>
          <last-name>Doe</last-name>
        </structured-name>
        <address1></address1>
        <contact-name>John Doe</contact-name>
        <company-name></company-name>
        <postal-code>XXXXXXXX</postal-code>
        <country-code>US</country-code>
        <city></city>
        <region></region>
      </buyer-billing-address>
      <order-summary>
        ...
```

This used to work before and the email was present on the billing address, I'm not sure why exactly its no longer listed on the response.

Also, the email is available if I search for the order_id directly through the web interface, but we obviously need to do this through an API.

[1] https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_History_API#Sample_Response_XML

Comment: Also, notice that on google's sample response on the [1] link the buyer-billing-address includes the email, just as it used to on our calls.